# PFQuery always return same results even though Parse server changed

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm developing an iOS project using Parse.com as backend server.

Basically, I'm currently implementing a very basic feature which just simply retrieve some objects with simple condition.

However, the objects can only be correctly retrieved the first time. No matter how I changed any values in Parse "Core" via Web, I still cannot get updated values by refreshing in the app.

For example, I have a class called "Event", the fields are changed from Parse server, but the result I retrieve are never updated.

```
        let eventServerQuery = Event.query()
        // I tried to clear all cached results
        PFQuery.clearAllCachedResults()
        eventServerQuery?.whereKey(EventFields.Campus.rawValue, equalTo: campus!)
        eventServerQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (allEvents, error) -> Void in
            self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            self.toggleRefreshButtonWithSpinner(false)
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                if allEvents?.count > 0 {
                    // Display on the map
                    for eventObject in allEvents! {
                        let event = Event.initializeFieldsFromPFObject(eventObject)
                        self.delegate?.addEventToMap(event)
                        self.events.append(event)
                        print("\(event.updatedAt)")
                        print("\(event.title) has \(event.numberOfTasks) tasks")
                    }
                    // Event TVC data source
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
```

If I delete the app in my device and run the project again, it will of course reload everything from scratch, so that the data will become correct again...

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I worked out by myself. I found that whenever the PFObject was pinned, its fields will not be updated. The solution is that the object need to be unpinned before retrieve from server.

```
        Event.unpinAllInBackground(events, block: { (success, error) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
            }else{
                self.events.removeAll()
                let eventServerQuery = Event.query()
                eventServerQuery?.whereKey(EventFields.Campus.rawValue, equalTo: self.campus!)
                eventServerQuery?.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (allEvents, error) -> Void in
                    print("Debug: retrieving events from server")
                    self.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
                    self.toggleRefreshButtonWithSpinner(false)
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    }else{
                        if allEvents?.count > 0 {
                            // Display on the map
                            for eventOnline in allEvents! {
                                let event: Event = eventOnline as! Event
                                event.pinInBackground()
                                self.delegate?.addEventToMap(event)
                                self.events.append(event)
                            }
                            // Event TVC data source
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

Welcome to add comments here regarding the internal logic of Parse library, as sometimes it is not quite clear I think.